# Read Registry Keys on different Windows Versions with NSIS

Tags: registry, nsis

I'm reading a Registry Key in my NSIS Script to detect wether Microsoft Visual 2010 Redistributable is installed or not.

`...
 ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}" "DisplayName"
         ${If} $R0 != ""
         Messagebox MB_OK "C++ 2010 Redistributable detected"
         goto yesCpp2010
         ${Else}
         MessageBox MB_OK "C++ 2010 not found"
         goto noCpp2010
         ${EndIf}
...`

I tried it on Windows 7 and it works. But it won't work on other Windows Versions if the Programms have other Keys. Do they have the same Keys?
If the Keys are different, is there a way to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUID can probably change with Service Pack's and security updates but [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx) claims you can just check the `Installed` DWORD under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64`.

For previous MSVC versions I would also suggest [querying SxS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WinSxS_QueryAssemblyInfo_to_check_if_assembly_is_installed) but I don't think 2010 uses that technology...

Comment: I just deinstalled and reinstalled C++ 2010 Redistributable but i dont have the entry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64". But i try "querying SxS". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget "\" character after Uninstall.

ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}" "DisplayName"